# block.super in Tornado template system

Tags: python, django, templates, tornado

In **Tornado** i have a base template with x block similar below:

```
{% block x %} x {% end %}
```

And in second template that inherited from base template i want to mix old value by new value similar django template tag, that is similar below code:

```
{% block x %} » {{ block.super }} « {% endblock %}
```

But in Tornado i cant use `{{ block.super }}`.

Tornado framework has equal django `block.super`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tornado does not currently have any equivalent to Django's `block.super`. The simplest workaround is to move the part you want to reuse into a separate file so it can be included in both places with `{% module Template('foo.html') %}`